# The assembly 'Dynamics.AX.ABC, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' failed to load

Tags: visual-studio-2019, microsoft-dynamics, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I'm getting below error after full-build in VSTS of project MS Dynamics365 F&O:

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Category    Source  Suppression State
Error       The assembly 'Dynamics.AX.ABC, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' failed to load due to the module 'Dynamics.AX.ABC.Class.EInvoiceAPI.netmodule' not being present. Please perform a full build of the module that produced this dll."

here ABC is my customer model and EInvoiceAPI is a class.

performed all troubleshooting steps like full build,db sync, restart IIS and batch services and VSTS open close & model references but nothing worked.

Please let me know your inputs?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if there is a .dll file and the Dynamics.AX.ABC.Class.EInvoiceAPI.netmodule file in the bin folder of the ABC module?
Did the build work before? Does the build have other compile errors? Does the build work on a new deployed environment?

Comment: @FH-Inway I have checked there is no such files in bin folder. build worked before. There is no other error except this. I haven't checked as I have only one environment.

Comment: @FH-Inway the below is example code where i wrote in EInvoiceAPI class(note: i have changed code not exact this one), I deleted due to some error after that i facing this error in VSTS2019 https://allaboutdynamic.com/2020/09/07/d365-fo-consume-call-restful-api-using-x-pass-request-header-post-json-message-in-body/

Comment: There is no dll file in bin. Anyway i have deployed new vm with updated version.